Reverse engineering of the tap-barcode of Tassimo T-Discs
I'm trying to reverse engineer the tap-barcode of the Tassimo T-Discs available here in Germany.
I read this post T-Disc ITF-Code up and down and tried around but found no solution yet.
Maybe someone else has also started to reverse engineer this.
As far as I know until now, the Barcode is a Code-128 with modified / shortened start and end sequence.
So the code starts with a 10 pattern and ends with 11 (1=black, 0=white) and consists of 5 bytes and therefore isn't scanable with normal apps.
Some t-discs I already read in:
Name                                                        ITF-Barcode     ITF-Code        Code-128 HEX        Code-128 BIN
Refill 180 ml                                               409193          40919           0x1241425853        0001 0010 0100 0001 0100 0010 0101 1000 0101 0011
Refill 60ml                                                 061780          06178           0x1828093d45        0001 1000 0010 1000 0000 1001 0011 1101 0100 0101
Jacobs Caffe Crema clasico XL                               297615          29761           0x00613b2813        0000 0000 0110 0001 0011 1011 0010 1000 0001 0011
Jacobs Caffe Crema mild XL                                  297615          29761           0x0f4e464c46        0000 1111 0100 1110 0100 0110 0100 1100 0100 0110
Friele Frokostkaffe                                         297615          29761           0x155e4a3c38        0001 0101 0101 1110 0100 1010 0011 1100 0011 1000
Espresso for Coffee Shop Flat White                         063210          06321           0x025a19601a        0000 0010 0101 1010 0001 1001 0110 0000 0001 1010
Espresso for Coffee Shop Iced Caramel latte                 061780          06178           0x1162045125        0001 0001 0110 0010 0000 0100 0101 0001 0010 0101
Gevalia Espresso (for Cappucino)                            061469          06146           0x07235f353e        0000 0111 0010 0011 0101 1111 0011 0101 0011 1110
Milk for Coffee Shop Selections White Choco coconut latte   064392          06439           0x09302e1209        0000 1001 0011 0000 0010 1110 0001 0010 0000 1001
Milk for Coffee Shop Toffee Nut Latte                       064392          06439           0x0811266224        0000 1000 0001 0001 0010 0110 0110 0010 0010 0100
Milk for Coffee Shop Iced Caramell Latte                    285308          28530           0x1209523249        0001 0010 0000 1001 0101 0010 0011 0010 0100 1001
Milk for Gevalia Cappuciono                                 061827          06182           0x065f5e2266        0000 0110 0101 1111 0101 1110 0010 0010 0110 0110

At the moment I can't really make sense of it and since I don't have enough reputation to ask in the mentioned thread I hope someone can help me out here.
Example picture of this tap-barcode:


What are you actually trying to do.? The codes (product number) does not need to have a pattern or mean anything..

Well, the Tap-Code, at least here in Germany, isn't the product code, but the brewing instructions for the Tassimo, as it is scanned when the brewing is started, and I guess, since there're no software updates possible and new T-Discs are sold all the time, that this code, similar to the old ITF6 one holds the instructions.
My intention is to "break the code" to configure my refillable capsules as I want.

is this a barcode of some kind? ... if it is, then please add some pictures to your post
